# make search result appear in the same page (Swing program)

Tags: java, swing

So, this is a program in swing for implementing a search functionality. It runs perfectly well. No problems there. My requirement is to make the search results appear beneath the same page. In this code, I have made the results to appear in a new Jframe that opens a new window. I basically don't want this. I want to make the search result appear in the same page. So, should I modify the code ? Any form of help is appreciated. :) Thanks !

### This is my code:-

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class r_search_1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame1;
    JLabel l0, l1, l2;
    JComboBox c1;
    JButton b1;
    Connection con;
    ResultSet rs, rs1;
    Statement st, st1;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    String ids;
    static JTable table;
    String[] columnNames = {"SECTION NAME", "REPORT NAME", "CONTACT", "LINK"};
    String from;
    Vector v = new Vector();

    r_search_1() 
    {
        l0 = new JLabel("Fetching Search Results...");
        l0.setForeground(Color.blue);
        l0.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        l1 = new JLabel("Search");
        b1 = new JButton("submit");

        l0.setBounds(100, 50, 350, 40);
        l1.setBounds(75, 110, 75, 20);
        b1.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 20);
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        setTitle("Search Executive Reports  ");
        setLayout(null);
        //setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(l0);
        add(l1);
        add(b1);

        try 
        {

            File dbFile = new File("executive_db.accdb");
            String path = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ= " + path);
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("select index_name from Index1");
           while (rs.next())
           {
                ids = rs.getString(1);
                v.add(ids);

            }
            c1 = new JComboBox(v);
            c1.setEditable(true);c1.setSelectedItem("");
            c1.setBounds(150, 110, 150, 20);

            add(c1);
            st.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
            showTableData();
        }
     }

    public void showTableData()
    {
        frame1 = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(model);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        from = (String) c1.getSelectedItem();

        String section_name = "";
        String report_name = "";
        String contact_name = "";
        String link = "";


        try
        {

        pst = con.prepareStatement("select distinct Section.Section_Name,Report.Report_Name,Report.Link,Contact.Contact_Name "
                        + "FROM (( Section INNER JOIN Report ON Report.Section_ID=Section.Section_ID ) INNER JOIN Contact ON Contact.Contact_ID=Report.Contact_ID )  LEFT JOIN Metrics ON Metrics.Report_ID=Report.Report_ID  "
                        + " WHERE Section.Section_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' OR Report.Report_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' OR Metrics.Metric_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' OR Contact.Contact_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' ");
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                section_name = rs.getString("Section_Name");
                report_name = rs.getString("Report_Name");
                contact_name = rs.getString("Contact_Name");
                link = rs.getString("Link");
                model.addRow(new Object[]{section_name, report_name, contact_name, link});
                i++;
            }
            if (i < 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                System.out.println(i + " Record Found");
            } else {
                System.out.println(i + " Records Found");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        frame1.add(scroll);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setSize(1000, 400);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new r_search_1();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @ Kevin Workman: Sorry if it wasn't clear. My question is just how to make the search results appear in the same page where the user types the string to search. Any clue how it should be done ?

Comment: Add a component that displays the results to the content pane of the currently visible JFrame. What have you tried?

Comment: @ Kevin Workman : I'm really confused about how I should do it ! I am naive to swing programming. Any help from your side ?

Comment: Which part of my suggestion was confusing to you? What have you tried?

Comment: @Kevin Workman: Oh no ! It's not your suggestion that is confusing. What I meant was that can you help me modify the code to accomplish what I want ? Because I don't know how to do that. Thanks !

Comment: I doubt anybody is going to write your code for you. I suggest you try something out and come back with what you tried. Good luck.

Comment: Crossposted: http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/88149-make-search-result-appear-same-page-swing-program.html

Comment: @Kevin Workman : So isn't it a good practice to cross post a question ?

Comment: If you're going to crosspost, you should at least let us know where else you've crossposted it, that way we don't waste our time repeating advice you've already received. Please read this: http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/cafe/6776-problems-cross-posting.html

Answer (score 0):

***Do not use Null layout***. Use a **BorderLayout**.

All your search functionality should be in the center panel.

```
add(mySearchPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Your results should be in the south panel. That way it will not shrink the center panel.

```
add(myResultsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

If there is nothing in the south panel, then it will shrink away making it seem like it is not there.

So, going into a little more detail, your **l0**,**l1**, and **b1** components should go into a panel (say myTopPanel), and be added to the center. Your **scroll** component should be added to the bottom panel.

```
setTitle("Search Executive Reports  ");
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

myTopPanel.add(l0);
myTopPanel.add(l1);
myTopPanel.add(b1);


add(myTopPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER)

add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER)
```

Comment: Sorry But I'm not clear how to incorporate your suggested edit in my code. Can u please tell me something with respect to my code. Thanks for replying ! :)

Comment: instead of setLayout(null); you should use other layoutmanagers. eg. setLayout(new BorderLayout()). Then you have a layoutmanager which can control how things are displayed. Without a layoutmanager, you will have to somehow figure out how to make the frame bigger at the bottom, and then attach the list data. Save yourself the trouble and learn about BorderLayout and Flowlayout

Comment: Thanks for enlightening Oliver ! Just 1 lame question..where should I add the add(mySearchPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); in my code. Sorry for the question bing too noob !

Comment: I've added more text to the answer. You need to add l0,l1, and b1 to the center, and scroll to the bottom.

Comment: :Thanks ! I'll surely implement them. Any more suggestions that I need to improve upon ?